# Laptop screen resolution not conforming to specs, double graphics card

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, resolution

I recently bought an Asus N73SV, according to the specs (and shown in the shop) it has a max screen resolution of 1920x1080.

However, I cannot raise the resolution above 1600x900 in  the control applet. The laptop uses two graphics cards: an Intel HD family and  a NVIDIA model. I understand that control between the two is switched intelligently.

I went back to the shop: it was the exact same laptop, it could be set to 1920x1080, only in the control applet the monitor was classified as a HSD173PUW1 where on my Laptop it was classified as a "Generic PnP monitor". I scourged the net and the Asus site for an .inf file but failed.

What can be the problem?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Is the reseller not able to resolve this?  If you just boought this, they should still have some interest in assuring it works. Possibly your system has a different screen?

Comment: @ChrisF: Win7-64

Comment: @Dave M: I checked: it is exactly the same model, it must be a configuration  issue

Comment: Understood, but I meant they should be able to make the laptop work as advsertised and sold. Or give you one that works as advertised.  @SkyBeam has some good points on this.

Answer (score 4):

The Asus N73SV is sold with two different display models:

- N73SV-V1G-TY283V: 17.3" GT WSXGA (1600x900) screen
- N73SV-V1G-TZ456Z: 17.3" GT WUXGA (1920x1080) screen

The high-res screen model also usually comes with a Blu-Ray drive while the WSXGA model comes with a DVD drive. I guess your one has a DVD drive only.

Well, the model numbers might differ in your country or based on other equipment included. But I think you got the point. Asus (and many other manufacturers) sell the same model with different hardware combination. So the model number "N73SV" does not say everything about the hardware.

If you just bought the laptop because of the high-res screen then you might ask the vendor whether he's going to exchange it (but he might charge you for the replacement). Check your bill whether it states that you got the WUXGA model. If it does, then you can return it and ask to get what you paid for. If not, then you probably just went to the store and noticed that the laptop is available in two price classes where you bought the cheaper one without checking or realizing that the specs are different. In this case it's strictly speaking your fault and you cannot insist on replacement. But of course you can ask the shop whether they are willing to do an exchange deal - else you can also sell your one and get a new one (the high-res model).

I don't think that adding the right screen type will change anything. Installing the correct INF file usually is recommended for wide-gamut displays where also a color profile is included. Even if Windows recognizes the screen as a generic PnP screen it is able to read the physical resolution from the panel and displays the correct maximum resolution. So Installing the INF file won't help to display a higher resolution.

Comment: It is the Z465 model, I checked the stickers on the bottom of both the model I bought as on the one in the shop. So that would mean that the wrong model was boxed in the factory!

Comment: +1  Good points.  Have seen this happen when two screen resolutions are available.  Sometimes an error but sometimes intentional on the part of a reseller

Comment: Well, I think the Z465 is probably a typo (TZ456T might be correct). In any case if the sticker says it's a WUXGA model but you got the WSXGA model it's a clear reason to give it back - no matter whether the error was done at Asus or your reseller and no matter whether it was done by mistake or on purpose. Your buying contract is with the reseller, so bring it back and insist on getting the correct model.